# Omit multiple factors in texreg

Tags: r, texreg

When using `texreg` I frequently use `omit.coef` to remove certain estimates (for fixed effects) as below.

```
screenreg(lm01,omit.coef='STORE_ID',custom.model.names = c("AA"))
```

In my `lm` model if I use multiple fixed effects how can I omit multiple variables? For example, I have two types of fixed effects - STORE_ID and Year, let's say.

This does not work.

```
screenreg(lm01,omit.coef=c('STORE_ID','Year'),custom.model.names = c("AA"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to consider regex instead, separated by an `|`. *Example:*

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp + drat, mtcars)
texreg::screenreg(fit)
# =====================
#              Model 1 
# ---------------------
# (Intercept)  23.99 **
#              (7.99)  
# cyl          -0.81   
#              (0.84)  
# disp         -0.01   
#              (0.01)  
# hp           -0.02   
#              (0.02)  
# drat          2.15   
#              (1.60)  
# ---------------------
# R^2           0.78   
# Adj. R^2      0.75   
# Num. obs.    32      
# =====================
# *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```

Now omitting:

```
texreg::screenreg(fit, omit.coef=c('disp|hp|drat'))
# =====================
#              Model 1 
# ---------------------
# (Intercept)  23.99 **
#              (7.99)  
# cyl          -0.81   
#              (0.84)  
# ---------------------
# R^2           0.78   
# Adj. R^2      0.75   
# Num. obs.    32      
# =====================
# *** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```

Answer (score 1):

`screenreg` allows you to include the `custom.coef.map` option and pass a list through it. This option allows you to directly select the variables you want to KEEP (instead of omit with `omit.coef`), and allows you to change the variables' names simultaneously:

```
screenreg(lm01, custom.coef.map = list("var1" = "First variable",
"var2" = "Second Variable", "var3" = "Third variable"))
```